Xamarin iOS ignoring padding style for ContentPage
Im try to set padding for ContentPage in different ways:

Direct in ContentPage tag

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                x:Class="SkeletonApp.Example.MainPage"
                Padding="10,15,10,15">
<!-- Content -->
</ContentPage>


Separate define in xaml-file

<ContentPage ...>
                <ContentPage.Padding>
                     <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                          <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,80,0,0" />
                     </OnPlatform>
                </ContentPage.Padding>
<!-- Content -->
</ContentPage>


In Application.Resources block

<Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True"> 
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=#FFFFFF, Dark=#000000}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,15,10,15"/>
</Style>

But in all cases iOS(Simulator or device) ignored this styles while the Android shows everything is fine.
Moreover, the iOS only ignores padding and applies color styles o_O
Im tested styling padding for other element(Label) - is fine
I guessed what UseSafeArea=True create a trouble but no. If set UseSafeArea=False or remove nothing to change
Why does this happen and how to deal with it?

UPD

App.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    x:Class="SkeletonApp.App"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:customePage="clr-namespace:SkeletonApp.View.Page;assembly=SkeletonApp"
    >
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True"> 
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,15,10,15"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

App.xaml.cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SkeletonApp.Example;

namespace SkeletonApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new TabBarNagivation();
        }

        protected override void OnStart() { }
        protected override void OnSleep() { }
        protected override void OnResume() { }
    }
}

TabBarNavigation.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="SkeletonApp.Example.TabBarNagivation"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SkeletonApp.Example"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <TabBar x:Name="TabBarMain">
        <ShellContent Title="Casual Page" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CasualPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Main Page" Icon="icon_about.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Additional Page" Icon="icon_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AdditionalPage}" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>

TabBarNavigation.xaml.cs
namespace SkeletonApp.Example
{
    public partial class TabBarNagivation : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
    {
        public TabBarNagivation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

CasualPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SkeletonApp.View.Page;assembly=SkeletonApp"
    x:Class="SkeletonApp.Example.CasualPage"
    Title="Casual Page">
    
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems> 
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="icon_about.png" Text="Change theme" Clicked="changeTheme_onCLicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <StackLayout Spacing="10">
        <Button
            x:Name="buttonLoadingPage1Timer"
            Margin="10,0,10,0"
            Clicked="timeCalculation_OnClicked"
            HeightRequest="55"
            Text="Run time calculation"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label
            x:Name="calculatedTime"
            Margin="10,0,10,0"
            FontSize="Medium"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="Time not yet calculated" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

CasualPage.xaml.cs
namespace SkeletonApp.Example
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CasualPage : ContentPage
    {
        public CasualPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timeCalculation_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((Label) FindByName("calculatedTime")).Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        private void changeTheme_onCLicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OSAppTheme currentTheme = Application.Current.RequestedTheme;

            Application.Current.UserAppTheme = currentTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark ? OSAppTheme.Light : OSAppTheme.Dark;
        }
    }
}

Screenshot with little colorfill

I cannot reproduce this issue on my side. It would be better if you could share more  relevant code. Do you use shell or just a ContentPage?

It used to be an issue but now has been fixed, Top Padding not working on iOS when it is set alone.. You could try updating your Xamarin Forms version to the latest to see if it helps.

Im using ContentPage under Shell and latest available Xamarin version - 5.0.0.2662. Added code listing and little visualization

This may relate to [Bug] Shell content padding on iOS default. And for iOS, the SetPaddingInsets api has been removed. That means we could not set the padding for the ContentPage in a Shell app.
Though we cannot set the Padding for a ContentPage, we could set the Padding for the layout, such as <StackLayout Spacing="10" Padding="10,15,10,15">
By the way, Xamarin will be end of support from May. It is recommend that you migrate Xamarin App to MAUI.
Xamarin Support Policy
Upgrade from Xamarin to .NET
